# Docker Swarm constraint to keep multiple containers together?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have three containers that need to run on the same Swarm node/host in order to have access to the same data volume.  I don't care which host they are delegated to - since it is running on Elastic AWS instances, they will come up and down without my knowing it.

This last fact makes it tricky even though it seems like it should be fairly common.  Is there a placement constraint that would allow this?  Obviously node.id or node.hostname are out as those are not constant.  I thought about labels - that would work, but then I have no idea how to have a "replacement" AWS instance automatically get the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swarm doesn't have the feature to put containers on the same host together yet (with your requirements of not using ID or hostname). That's known as "Pods" in Kubernetes. Docker Swarm takes a more distributed approach. You could try to hack together a label assignment on new instance startup but that isn't ideal.

In Swarm the way to solve this problem today is with using a different volume driver plugin then the built-in "local" driver. [Here's a list of certified ones](https://store.docker.com/search?category=volume&q=&type=plugin). The key in Swarm is to not use local storage on a node for volumes. Those volumes will get lost when the node dies anyway, so it's best in Swarm to move your volumes to shared storage.

In AWS I'd suggest you try EFS as shared storage if you need multiple containers to access it at once, and use either Docker's CloudStor driver (comes with [Docker for AWS template](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-aws/)) or the [REX-Ray storage orchestrator](https://rexray.io/) solution which ensures shared data paths (NFS, EFS, S3, etc.) are connected to the correct node for the correct Service task.